# Difference between a module and a package in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, package

I am new to Node.js. What is the difference between a "package" and a "module" in Node.js?

Answer (score 83):

[Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) are libraries for Node.js. See the below excerpt from the API:

> Node.js has a simple module loading system. In Node.js, files and modules
>   are in one-to-one correspondence.

Examples of modules:

- Circle.js
- Rectangle.js
- Square.js

A package is one or more modules (libraries) grouped (or packaged) together. These are commonly used by other packages or a project of your own. Node.js uses a [package manager](https://npmjs.org/), where you can find and install thousands of packages.

Example of a package:

```
Shapes             <- Package name
  - Circle.js      <-
  - Rectangle.js   <- Modules that belong to the Shapes package
  - Square.js      <-
```

Essentially, you could install the package, `Shapes`, and have access to the Circle, Rectangle, and Square modules.

Comment: The quoted text was there until the [end of 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20171125031821/https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), when it changed to this phrasing: *"In the Node.js module system, each file is treated as a separate module"*, as quoted in @userA57's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51731037/3002584).

Answer (score 18):

A **module** is a single JavaScript file that has some reasonable functionality.

A **package** is a directory with one or more modules inside of it and a package.json file which has metadata about the package.

A package can be very ***simple*** for example, *underscore* just has a single JavaScript file (we see two versions of it, regular and minified version and package.json)

```
open@open-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/module-package-demo/node_modules/underscore
$ dir
LICENSE       README.md      underscore-min.js
package.json  underscore.js  underscore-min.js.map
```

Whereas a more ***complex*** package like *Express* has one JavaScript file in the root, but inside its sub-directories has quite a few more JavaScript files and more within sub-directories of that

```
open@open-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/module-package-demo/node_modules/express
$ dir
History.md  index.js  lib  LICENSE  package.json  Readme.md
```

Now it's very common for people to refer to a package as a module.

Answer (score 15):

I searched [the **Node.js** documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/) and found [their def for module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules):

> In the Node.js module system, each file is treated as a separate **module**.

npm has some official defs [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/packages#understanding-packages-and-modules).

> A **package** is a file or directory that is described by a package.json file.
>   A **module** is any file or directory in the node_modules directory that can be loaded by the Node.js require() function.
>   **Note**: Since modules are not required to have a package.json file, not all modules are packages. Only modules that have a package.json file are also packages.

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 Examples are great, but those examples are only useful for React users.

Comment: I would recommend giving examples as it helps users to understand quickly. You can add if you find general ones.

Answer (score 5):

Everything what you can `require()` is a module. In most cases in the [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) world, it's one file per module.

A package can contain several modules, but you usually load the entry point (`main`), which is specified in the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) or its **index.js** if no `main` property is provided, for instance: `require('express')`.

But you can also require another file (not the main file) if you know the location. For instance, `require("express/lib/application")` (in Node.js you can omit the extension: **.js**).

A package can access modules from other packages if they are listed in the `dependencies` property of the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies).

Actually npm installs all the packages into **node_modules** which is confusing, because it should be **node_packages**.

*[Modules | Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)*

Comment: [CommonJS died in late 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, what made you say that? From the Wiki you linked to: *CommonJS's module specification is **widely used today**, in particular for server-side JavaScript programming with Node.js.*.

Answer (score 3):

Every Node.js application is a `package` and should have a `package.json` file. Those applications act as middleware (or the equivalent of libraries) and are meant to be installed inside other applications are `modules`.

In short, all `modules` are `packages`, but not all `packages` are meant to be used as `modules`, though many can be.

Modules will be installed, if listed as `dependencies` in the `package.json` file, and placed into the `node_modules` folder, but `npm` recurses through their `package.json` files to add the `modules` they rely on.

Comment: As per the npm doc- https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules, in order for a module to be a package, it has to follow 1 of the 3 condition. So if the module is only js file, it cannot necessarily have a `package.json` file. Hence, it cannot be a package. Therefore, your assertion that **"All modules are packages"** is wrong.

Comment: Also, refer to the **Note** section of the doc.

Answer (score 3):

From https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules:

> ### About packages
>
> A **package** is a file or directory that is described by a **package.json**
>   file. A package must contain a **package.json** file in order to be
>   published to the npm registry.
>
> [...]
>
> ### About modules
>
> A **module** is any file or directory in the **node_modules**
>   directory that can be loaded by the Node.js **require()** function.
>
> To be loaded by the Node.js **require()** function, a module must be one
>   of the following:
>
> - A folder with a **package.json** file containing a **"main"** field.
> - A folder with an **index.js** file in it.
> - A JavaScript file.
>
> ---
>
> **Note**: Since modules
>   are not required to have a **package.json** file, not all modules are
>   packages. Only modules that have a **package.json** file are also
>   packages.
>
> ---
>
> In the context of a Node program, the **module** is also the
>   thing that was loaded *from* a file. For example, in the following
>   program:
>
> `var req = require('request')`
>
> we might say that “The variable **req**
>   refers to the **request** module”.

Answer (score -1):

**In short**:

A `module` with `package.json` file can be called a package.

The term `package` comes from Node Package Manager(NPM). It is set of files along with `package.json` and has nothing to do with `Node.js`. You can share your `module` with other developers by publishing it as a `package`(by adding `pacakge.json`) in `NPM registry` so that it can be used by other developers.

`Node.js` consists of only `modules`. Any file or directory is called as `module` in `Node.js`.

```
(Module)
Demo
 -> app.js
```

```
(Package)
Demo
 -> app.js
 -> package.json
```

**Long version**:

The term `package` comes from `Node Package Manager`(NPM). As NPM only accepts `packages` and `package` is set a of files along with `package.json` it has nothing to do with `Node.js`. You can share your `module` with other developers by publishing it as a `package`(by adding `pacakge.json`) in `NPM registry` so that it can be used by other developers.

Similarly when you install a `package` from NPM, it will be installed as a `module` into the application.

In `Node.js` there is no such requirement for a `module` to have `package.json` file. So, a module that has `package.json` will be eligible to be published in the `NPM registry` and it can be called as a `package`.

Ex: `express` is a Node.js `module` which is published as a `package` in NPM `registry`.

```
npm install express --save
```

Above statement installs `express` `package` from `NPM` as a `module` into Node.js project.

```
const express = require('express')
```

will gives the `module.export` object of express `module` which is installed as a `package` from `NPM`.

FYR: https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules

Answer (score -2):

**Package**:

A package is a file or directory that is described by a package.json file.
A package must contain a package.json file in order to be published to the npm registry.

**Module**:

A module is any file or directory in the node_modules directory that can be loaded by the Node.js require() function.

To be loaded by the Node.js require() function, a module must be one of the following:

- A folder with a package.json file containing a "main" field.
- A folder with an index.js file in it. A JavaScript file.
- A module is any file or directory in the node_modules directory that
  can be loaded by the Node.js require() function.

In the context of a Node program, the module is also the thing that was loaded from a file. For example, in the following program:

```
var req = require('request')
```

we might say that “The variable req refers to the request module”.

**Note**:

Since modules are not required to have a package.json file,
not all modules are packages. Only modules that have a package.json file are also
packages.

Comment: Explaining my downvote: (1) this is a near-exact replica of a previous answer — the one by @eyal-levin; and (2) unlike his answer, yours doesn't cite the source of the text, which makes it seem (incorrectly) like it's your writing. I'd suggest removing this answer or editing it to provide details that are not already present in the other answers.

Comment: Ya Sure @waldyrious , going forward will mention the source  of text .