# Node: difference between project and package

Tags: node.js, package

I understand the [difference between a module and a package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20008442/5353461), but what is difference between a project and a package in Node.js?

It seems every project needs a `package.json` file, implying every project is a package... is every package a project as well?

Comment: Every package is a project, but not every project is a package.

Comment: I'm not sure "project" is such a definite term, this might be opinion based. I would consider a project to be made up of one or more packages. I think that is the opposite of your view @AndrewLi?

Comment: @Matt In the context of my statement, I mean packages as libraries such as packages in the NPM registry, so I guess it is pretty subjective. Yes, a project is made up of many packages, but I'm saying all packages in the NPM registry are inherently 'projects' in a general sense, but not all projects are packages put into the NPM registry, such as a private web app which is a project, but not necessarily a package that's distributed.

Comment: @AndrewLi Projects like lodash or ones that use plugin systems change the "package is a project" thing for me. For example, the lodash build process publishes over [400 packages](https://www.npmjs.com/~jdalton) for the different formats and functions. Babel core plugins are another example that make it vague for me.

Comment: In any case I don't think there is a particular special meaning for project in Node.js, just the standard vague IT term. (as opposed to say Intellij IDEA which has a specific idea of what a project is)

Answer (score 1):

Both are differ in terms of their **scope** and **purpose**.

Let's say you are creating a file uploading program. We can categories it's purpose into single sentence. This program serves file uploading code that everybody can use. On the other hand Projects has a larger scope. They comprise of various packages. A single Project can serve many purpose. Ex. Employee management System.

A *Package* on the other hand *is a part of Project* which serves a particular purpose.

Packages are useful for many things. For example, you could store a set of files that do a given task TASK (uploading, database, authentication mechanism etc.) in a package named task.

Packages are a way for developers to find easily and quickly a file, knowing what the role of the file is. Whenever your project starts growing, packages are essential.

Comment: If the scope of a project is small enough, then it could be implemented in a single package.

Comment: Yes. It can be.