# yarn: Always use `yarn add --link-duplicates`

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

`yarn help add` says:

> ```
> --link-duplicates       create hardlinks to the repeated modules in node_modules
> ```

I assume this is about hardlinking files since [files and modules are in one-to-one correspondence](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules), and linux doesn't support non-root directory hardlinks. I could be wrong though, since [the `node_modules` directory should really be called `node_packages`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30964464/5353461).

1. Is there any reason why I wouldn't want to always use this option to save disk space?
2. Can I enable `--link-duplicates` as a default so I don't have to type it out each time?

Answer (score 2):

1. Node packages may have issues with symlinks, [this issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2734) shows that it's unpredictable. If you verified your app and dependencies to be working with `--link-duplicates` you could enable the option, but it could suddenly fail when you make changes.
2. `yarn config set link-duplicates true [--global]`, or [create a .yarnrc file](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarnrc/) containing `link-duplicates true`

Comment: link-duplicates does not do any *symlink* stuff even in the version mentioned in the question. The hard link collision issue has also been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since symlinks are not used, this is mostly a non-issue. But packages that modify their own `node-modules` do exist, and this has a chance of modifying *all* other copies (depending on [whether the action is in-place](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249044)). One example is `npm` itself with the `audit` thing, although no sane person would causally mix `yarn` with `npm`.
2. The correct name for the flag is `--install.link-duplicates`. So the command is `yarn config set [--global] -- --install.link-duplicates true`. Note the `--` in the command – it tells `yarn` to not interpret the `install` thing as an option.
3. If you are only looking to save disk space, the correct way is to do *nothing* if you are using a modern filesystem (BTRFS or XFS on Linux). Yarn already uses `fs.copyFile` with `COPYFILE_FICLONE`, and will use that if available. If you are using APFS, NTFS or ReFS, [you still need to wait](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/499#issuecomment-644399773).