# If "Node.js modules are a type of package that can be published to npm," how can "...not all modules are packages" be true?

Tags: node.js, npm

I found an official npm article titled "[Creating Node.js modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules)." The first line says:

> Node.js modules are a type of [package](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules) that can be published to npm.

But when you click on the "package" link, that article says:

> Note: Since modules are not required to have a `package.json` file, not all modules are packages. Only modules that have a `package.json` file are also packages.

These quotes seem to contradict. Is one a typo, or am I missing some context that makes both statements possible?

---

I found this question first: [Difference between a module and a package in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008442/difference-between-a-module-and-a-package-in-node-js) It is well written, but I can't square it with the first quote in my question.

Comment: Module is what you get when you `import`, package is what you get when you `npm install`. All packages are modules but not all modules are packages.

Comment: @morganney That makes sense to me... until I reread this first quote. What you are saying is it has a typo, right? It claims all modules are packages?

Comment: Sure, I would agree that it could be worded better. "Node.js modules **can be** published to npm as a package." There is also the fact that an npm package can be a tar, or a link to a github repo, or a tag, etc., so in that sense a Node.js module _is a type of package_ that can be published to npm.